# Won't complete hardware update

Tags: oem

'Package operation failed'

```
Unpacking fglrx-core (from .../fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx 2:14.201-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, the file `/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh` is part of both packages `fglrx-core` and `fglrx`.

You have two possibilities

- Don't use the packages from a PPA or a downloaded deb if you don't know, how to use it

Or

- Remove the officially package fglrx via

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove fglrx
  ```